# Filtering couchdb linked documents

Tags: couchdb

I'm using the following map function to get user documents that are 'linked' to from a group:

```
function(doc) {
  var i, id;
  if(doc.type == 'group' && !doc.deletedAt) {
    for (i = 0; i < doc.users.length; ++i) {
        id = doc.users[i];
        emit(doc._id, {'_id': id});
    }
    emit(doc._id, null);
  }
}
```

A group looks like:

```
{
   "_id": "3979684300c58a4c90c7c6e0d6033dce",
   "_rev": "90-283daf6cb4edfd838a50121e3364f4cb",
   "type": "group",
   "name": "test",
   "description": "test",
   "users": [
       "544f4718732b51506d9de60a4e000505",
       "63de6351a30879ee091b248c930a9254",
       "5684612479ba328ba2575c60e800adee"
   ],
   ... other fields
}
```

A user lookes like:

```
{
   "_id": "8f87c698f119044890c5e788cd0028c1",
   "_rev": "5-441da938e50fb692da55d74231f614c2",
   "empId": "",
   "type": "user",
   "disabled": false,
   "username": "fred",
   "firstName": "Fred",
   "lastName": "Jones",
   ...other fields
}
```

The map function works, but I need to filter out user documents that have a 'deletedAt' property set. Is this possible in the map function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this without changing the structure of your documents. Instead of storing an array of users in the group document, you should store an array of groups in the user document. Then your map function can look like this:

```
function(doc {
  var i;
  if(doc.type == 'user' && !doc.deletedAt) {
    for (i = 0; i < doc.groups.length; ++i) {
      emit(doc.groups[i], null);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Changing the document structure would introduce a bunch of problems elsewhere in the app so unfortunately this isn't an option for me.